# Google shows some of my pages in https

Tags: https

I had the SSL installed on my site for a day and uninstalled it. Now in serps, google shows some of the pages in https version. I don't think this is a duplicate content issue because only one version of the web page shows up in serps. I'm not sure how to fix this because the mix of http hand https show up.

Why does google randomly show https version of my pages?
How can i tell google to use the http version of those random pages?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think more information is needed to fully answer this question, however, most likely Google is showing the HTTPS version of your page because your site was using HTTPs at the time when Google visited and indexed your page, thus the HTTPS version was cached.

You can partially manage your search page and request that Google re-index your site from Google Web Developer tools. https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/. However, the change isn't guaranteed and won't take place immediately.

Furthermore, you can control whether a visitor uses HTTPS or HTTP when visiting your site via standard redirects. In other words, update your webserver or web application so if someone visits `http://mysite` they will be redirected (preferably with a 301 status code for SEO reasons) to `https://mysite`.

Finally, as a general practice, you should really use HTTPS as browsers may highlight warnings for non-secured traffic in the future. For sites I manage, "http" requests are automatically redirected to the "https" of the same URL to ensure all traffic is always over a secure connection.